# if when Firebase successful Auth another page React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm using react native. I want it to open the usrFirst.js screen when the Firebase user login is successful. How do I do that? So I want to open another page when the login is successful. browserhistory.push ( './ src / components / usrfirst.js'); I tried the code but it doesn't work. I want to open usrfirst.js if the login is successful.

```
....
    import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';

      addUser = (username,passw) => {
        const user = username;
        const pass = passw;

        const currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;

    }
    getData = (email) => {
        firebase.database().ref('/users')
        .once('value', (snapshot) => {
        })
    }

    export default class App extends React.Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {};
        this.addUser = addUser;
      }

      async componentDidMount() {
         const { user } = await firebase.auth().signInAnonymously();
         console.warn('User -> ', user.toJSON());
    if (this.state.userLoggedin) {  user
        browserHistory.push('./src/components/usrFirst.js');
        } else {
          }
        }
        // initialize firebase
        await firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        firebase.messaging().hasPermission()
          .then(enabled => {
            if (enabled) {
              firebase.messaging().getToken().then(token => {
                console.log("LOG: ", token);
              })
              // user has permissions
            } else {
              firebase.messaging().requestPermission()
                .then(() => {
                  alert("User Now Has Permission")
                })
                .catch(error => {
                  alert("Error", error)
                  // User has rejected permissions  
                });
            }
          });
      }

      render() {
        const store = createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));
        this.addUser("a","user1");
        this.addUser('b','user2');
        getData("a");
        return (
          <Provider store={store}>
            <Router />
          </Provider>
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: You can't use normal react-dom navigation in react natie, remember that react native doesn't run in the browser, the code is compile and ran either ios or android devices, hence you have to use a plugin for page navigation, like react navigation or react native navigation.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: I'd recommend you to follow the documentation here, https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.60/navigation.